# Creating a loop which iterate below 1ms using AutoResetEvent.WaitOne with TimeSpan

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to create a loop with interval less than 1ms by using a `TimeSpan` initiated with 8000 ticks (1 tick = 100ns, thus 8000 ticks equals to 0.8ms or 800us):

```
    private static void MeasureAutoResetEvent()
    {
        TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(8000L); // 800us
        double elapsed = 0;
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        while (true)
        {
            watch.Restart();
            autoResetEvent.WaitOne(interval);
            watch.Stop();
            elapsed = ResolveTicks(UoM.Microsecond, watch.ElapsedTicks);

            Console.WriteLine(elapsed); // <- Does not writes ±800
        }
    }
```

`UoM` enum and `ResolveTicks()` method are defined as follows:

```
    public enum UoM
    {
        Second,
        Millisecond,
        Microsecond,
        Nanosecond,
    }

    public static double ResolveTicks(UoM uom, long ticks)
    {
        return
            uom == UoM.Millisecond ? ticks * 1e3 / Stopwatch.Frequency :
            uom == UoM.Microsecond ? ticks * 1e6 / Stopwatch.Frequency :
            uom == UoM.Nanosecond ? ticks * 1e9 / Stopwatch.Frequency :
            ticks * 1 / Stopwatch.Frequency;
    }
```

I'm using `Stopwatch` to measure time used by `autoResetEvent.WaitOne(interval);`. However, the output at the console does not writes ±800. Does anyone knows what's wrong with my codes above?

Comment: @George Replaced `elapsed = ResolveTicks(UoM.Microsecond, watch.ElapsedTicks)` with `elapsed = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;`. Now the output writes 0, which does make sense as the `TimeSpan` is below 1ms. Any idea?

Comment: Detecting a time-out requires a clock.  That clock on Windows ticks 64 times per second by default.  If you run your program while also visiting SO with a browser then you tend to see it tick 100 times per second.  A rate that's ideal to animate GIFs.  If that browser is Chrome then you'll discover why Google likes to give away free software to promote its products.  A high clock rate is bad for power consumption and battery life.  You can get it to tick once every millisecond by pinvoking timeBeginPeriod().  But, you know, don't be evil :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `.WaitOne()` is only accurate to between 5 and 20 ms (generally speaking).

So of course, if you try to wait for 800us, it's going to be nowhere close.

The resolution of `.WaitOne()` is determined by the current [Windows Timer Resolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Since `.WaitOne()` is only accurate to between 5 and 20ms, is it safe to assume that the loop iteration will iterate below 1ms if i removed `.WaitOne()`?

Comment: If you remove the wait, each iteration of the loop is likely to execute in much less than 1 ms.

Answer (score 1):

For normal day-to-day use timers are sufficiently precise, but not perfectly precise. When you move into the milliseconds realm (or worse, below it), the task switching mechanisms become influential. The task switching also depends on the platform (round-robin on Windows, several ones on Linux depending on kernel). There are Linux kernels which are specifically compiled for RT (realtime) applications and can guarantee specific response times (depending on hardware).

Presuming that your code is correct and you run on Windows, you can try to set the [process priority to the highest level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (realtime) and pin the core so that it always runs on the same core (so that the various L1, L2, L3 CPU caches are warmed-up properly). Otherwise you stumble into jittering which is caused by the task switching.